# I need to pass values from csv to the http request during one single run in jmeter

Tags: csv, jmeter

I have csv data set config of locations and i need to pass those to http request in single run for each user i.e if i have 4 locations then i need the http request to be called 4 times wherein those locations are passed one by one sequentially.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing your CSV file and knowing how the HTTP Request is supposed to look like.

If you're talking about [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) - by default (given ["Sharing Mode"](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-csv-dataset-config) of "All threads") each JMeter thread (virtual user) reads next line from the CSV file on each iteration.

So if you want to pass 4 values in 1 request - make sure that they all reside in one line.

If you cannot manipulate the CSV file you can consider switching to [__CSVRead() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) where you can specify when to proceed to the next line.

Comment: The data file has the latitude and longitude . HTTP REQUEST:https://api.drivevegas.k8.devfactory.com/rest/acdr?latitude=${Latitude}&longitude=${Longitude}&heading=0&speed=0&course=90&sequence=1670427622&carCategories=REGULAR                                                                                               CSV Data file:Latitude,Longitude
36.10803655487475,-115.16748588704128
36.10805389068134,-115.16570490025539
36.106112256560955,-115.16570490025539
36.10547081331421,-115.16656320714016
36.10546214512636,-115.16748588704128
36.097084543359564,-115.17586335211487